# How to get Localized Date and Time from SYSTEMTIME

Tags: winapi

I have a SYSTEMTIME and I am trying to get a localized string with both the date and time values from it. API's like GetDateFormat/GetTimeFormat get either the date or time - but not both.

Is there an API that is available that'll get me the localized string with both the date and time from a SYSTEMTIME?

Comment: I see that you're looking for a single function doing that, but couldn't you just concatenate them ?

Comment: This doesn't work and is not recommended. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292178(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I see, you need to have a correct date and time order (or have a separator between them if there is some). Good question!

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API doesn't have a date/time format string.  It has separate date and time format strings.

.Net does have the `DateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern`, but looking in Reflector this seems to be initialised to:

```
LongDatePattern + " " + LongTimePattern
```

and that's the value it has for all 354 cultures on my Windows 7 PC.  You'd only see something that didn't fit this pattern if a program had created a custom .Net culture and defined it differently.

I've worked on software that's sold all over the world and nobody's ever complained about us using date and time separated with a space.

Comment: So .NET established locale pattern on this for the whole world :-) +1